# Question on equivalence relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

In set theory a relation is said to be equivalence if the relation is,.

1. Reflexive
2. Symmetric
3. Transitive

I would like to know if the following relation is an equivalence one.

$R = \{ (m,n) \in Z \times Z \; : \; m - n \text{ is even} \}$,

where $Z$ is the set of all integers.

Here's why I think the relation is not equivalence.

1. To be reflexive let us consider $m = n = 4$. By the relation $m-n = 0$, which is not even. Thus it is not reflexive.

...
But the text book I'm referring to (Analysis by S.R Lay) states that the relation is an equivalence one.

Can someone explain to me why it is such. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: $0$ _is_ even ..

Comment: @Hippalectryon is there a proof? It can be both even and odd right?

Comment: Define an even number to be any number of the form $2n$ for an $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then choose $n=0$. Hence $0$ is even.

Comment: By definition, a number $n$ is even iff it can be written $n=2k$ where $k$ is an integer

Comment: No, it can only be even. It can never be odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $m-m=0$ is even. So reflexivity holds.
2. Suppose $m-n=2k$ (i.e. that $m-n$ is even). Then $n-m=-2k$, so n-m is also even. So the symmetric property holds.
3. Suppose $m-n=2k$, and $l-m=2j$. Then $l-n=l-m+m-n=2k+2j=2(k+j)$, so $m-n$ and $l-m$ even implies $l-n$ even. So transitivity holds.